# Redirigir en React después de hacer logOut (props.history.push no funciona)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Por qué props.history.push no funciona en este sencillo botón? Alguna otro enfoque que podría implementar para que se le rediriga al usuario a la pagina principal ("/") cuando click el boton de logout?

**Navbar.js**:

```js
handleLogOut = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    try{
      Auth.signOut()
      this.props.auth.setAuthStatus(false)
      this.props.auth.setUser(null)
      // no funciona
      this.props.history.push('/')
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

```html
<a href="/" onClick={this.handleLogOut} className="button is-primary">
                    Log out
              </a>
```

En el componente de hacer **Login.js** sin embargo si que funciona:

```js
handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Form validation
    this.clearErrorState();
    const error = Validate(event, this.state);
    if (error) {
      this.setState({
        errors: { ...this.state.errors, ...error }
      });
    }

try{
        const user = await Auth.signIn(this.state.username, this.state.password)
        console.log(user)
        this.props.auth.setAuthStatus(true)
        this.props.auth.setUser(user)
        // Si correctamente redirige a esa pagina:
        this.props.history.push("/news");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
  };
  
}
```

Las props las paso desde **App.js**:

```js
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    isAuthenticating: true,
    user: null
  }

  setAuthStatus = (authenticated) => {
    this.setState({
      isAuthenticated: authenticated
    })
  }

  setUser = (user) => {
    this.setState({
      user: user
    })
  }

  async componentDidMount(){
    try{
      const session = await Auth.currentSession();
      this.setAuthStatus(true)
      console.log(session)
      const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
      this.setUser(user)
    } catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
    this.setState({isAuthenticating:false})
  }

  render() {
    const authProps = {
      isAuthenticated: this.state.isAuthenticated,
      user: this.state.user,
      setAuthStatus: this.setAuthStatus,
      setUser: this.setUser
    }
    return (
      !this.state.isAuthenticating &&
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Navbar auth={authProps} />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <Home {...props} auth={authProps}/>} />
              <Route exact path="/news" render={(props) => <News {...props} auth={authProps}/>} />
             
              <Route exact path="/login" render={(props) => <Login {...props} auth={authProps}/>}  />
              <Route exact path="/register" render={(props) => <Register {...props} auth={authProps}/>}/>
           
    
            </Switch>
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

El logout funciona bien simplemente no me redirige a ninguna parte, se queda en la pestaña dónde el usuario clickó el logout , y lo que quería es que redirigiese a ("/") (la pagina principal).

Si me modifico la función quitandola el sync y poniéndo el método en primer lugar, si que funciona, sin embargo si lo hago así, no se realiza el logout:

```js
handleLogOut = (event) => {
    // lo incorporo en primer lugar
    this.props.history.push('/')
    event.preventDefault()
    try{
       Auth.signOut()
      this.props.auth.setAuthStatus(false)
      this.props.auth.setUser(null)
      
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Este tema me suena... Prueba a redirigir a una ruta ya definida, p.e. a `/news`, ¿te redirige? Creo recordar que en su momento cree una ruta específica '/home` pero no recuerdo de si funciono o encontré otra solución. El caso es que las rutas no son reales, son virtuales... y como que concatena, entonces con lo que estas haciendo, le añades la barra al final de tu actual ubicación y por eso no se "mueve".

Comment: No me redirige tampoco aunque le ponga /news

Comment: Prueba a quitar el atributo `exact` de la ruta a la que rediriges

Comment: @Orici Si se lo quito entonces siempre me va a cargar la pagina principal y entonces eso no me interesa. :(

Comment: Lo quitas en `/news` o la que sea, no en `/`

Answer (score 1):

He creado una pequeña estructura con *React 16* y "react-rooter-dom" de sólo dos páginas: *Home* y *Test*. Ambas tienen enlaces a pie de página para moverse entre ellas.

Todo el código esta en [Github](https://github.com/oricis/react-routing) para descargarlo y probar.

El contenido del fichero de routing es:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './views/Home.jsx';
import Test from './views/Test.jsx';

function App() {

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Home />} />
        <Route path="/home" render={() => <Home />} />
        <Route path="/test" render={() => <Test />} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Con respecto a tu código, he sustituido `Router` por `BrowserRouter` y sólo uso el atributo `exact` como te indique en los comentarios previos para la ruta `'/'`.

En cuanto a los enlaces para ir a *Home* tengo (en la página *Test*):

```
<div className="links">
    <Link to="/">Home page with route "/"</Link>
    <span> | </span>
    <Link to="/home">Home page with route "/home"</Link>
</div>
```

> Editado

En cuanto a una ***redirección condicionada*** (si se ha cerrado sesión por ejemplo), se puede usar `Redirect` de "react-rooter-dom" dentro del `render()` del componente. Es decir, la sesión se guarda en `props`, su estado se actualiza al pulsar *logout* cuando entra en `render()` si NO hay sesión en `props`:

```
return <Redirect to='/home' />
```

en caso contrario renderiza el componente de la forma habitual.

```
return (<div>Lo que sea</div>);
```

Comment: Hola, no estoy seguro si tu código es exactamente lo que busco, mi problema está en que quiero que se redirija a una página una vez que una función es disparada. (Lo he intentado con el método this.props.history.push hasta ahora)

Comment: @JavierCake he extendido mi respuesta con una posible solución para redireccionar en caso de cierre de sesión.

Comment: No es mala idea la verdad no sabía lo de Redirect! Lo único que se me complica un poco para implementarlo. Por qué la función de logout la tengo en la Navbar y segun si esta logeado o no renderiza una tipo de navbar u otra, entonces no puedo añadir el Redirect. Igualmente te dejo un voto arriba, gracias.

Comment: @JavierCake depende de como planteaste la arquitectura de la *app* te va a servir una u otra solución, yo en la que implemente esta solución tengo un sólo *navbar* que controla "todo": renderiza diferentes botones según el caso (como el de login o el de logout) y según donde clicas emite el evento hacia arriba a un componente principal, que trasmite por `props` hacia los componentes hijos, entonces al cerrar sesión, el nuevo estado llega a la página actual y  hay entra en acción el condicional y `Redirect`. Gracias por el voto.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a crearte tu propio browserHistory y pasarsele al Router como parametro y luego importas tu history en el componente que le necesites y realizas el .push('/').

Por ejemplo:
history.js

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

En el componente donde tienes el Router le importas y se los pasas al Router

```
<Router history={history}>
```

Y en el componente que te haga falta importas el History que has creado previamente y haces un push a la ruta que quieras.
Por ejemplo.

```
import history from '/history';

 history.push('/');
```

Si tienes las rutas como constantes mejor :)

Comment: A que te refieres con las rutas como constantes? Probé lo que me dices y sigue sin funcionar me temo. Creo que es algo relacionado con la funcion handleLogOut. He probado a hacerla síncrona, y poner el método history.push el primero, y si que funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error esta en la validación que estas haciendo en el componente **App.js** en el mismo tienes un estado **this.state.isAuthenticated** el cual cuando no estas autenticado no permite que se rendericen las rutas por lo cual aunque redirecciones a **/** o /news el router no podrá localizarlas.

Intenta modificando el código del render en App.js

```
render() {
    const authProps = {
      isAuthenticated: this.state.isAuthenticated,
      user: this.state.user,
      setAuthStatus: this.setAuthStatus,
      setUser: this.setUser
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Navbar auth={authProps} />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <Home {...props} auth={authProps}/>} />
              <Route exact path="/news" render={(props) => <News {...props} auth={authProps}/>} />
              <Route exact path="/login" render={(props) => <Login {...props} auth={authProps}/>}  />
              <Route exact path="/register" render={(props) => <Register {...props} auth={authProps}/>}/>
            </Switch>
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Cierto, la verdad es que no se para que tengo ese código. Bueno igualmente lo probé pero sigue sin funcionar :( Gracias de todas formas